# Converting WinRT Interface to C# Problems

Tags: c#, c++, com

I've been trying to convert this WinRT interface from its C++ Origin Code, to C# based code:

**IDL File:**

```
namespace Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web{

[version(1)]
[uuid(07650a66-66ea-489d-aa90-0dabc75f3567)]
interface ITokenBrokerInternalStatics : IInspectable {

    HRESULT filler_GetTokenSilently();
    HRESULT filler_GetSecureInputParameters();
    HRESULT filler_ReportBackgroundCompletion();
    HRESULT filler_FindAccount();
    HRESULT filler_FindAccountForApp();
    HRESULT filler_FindAccountForProvider();

    HRESULT FindAllAccountsAsync(
        [out][retval] Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorView<Windows.Security.Credentials.WebAccount > *> ** operation);

}

[version(1)]
[static(Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web.ITokenBrokerInternalStatics, 1)]
[marshaling_behavior(agile)]
[threading(both)]
runtimeclass TokenBrokerInternal {
}

}
```

**CPP File:**

```cpp
auto tokenBrokerStatics = get_activation_factory<TokenBrokerInternal, Windows::Foundation::IUnknown>();
auto statics = tokenBrokerStatics.as<ITokenBrokerInternalStatics>();
auto accounts = statics.FindAllAccountsAsync().get();
```

This is what I got so far:

```cs
using PInvoke;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web;
using Windows.Security.Credentials;
using GuidAttribute = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute;

namespace Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web
{

    
    [Version(1)]
    [Guid("07650a66-66ea-489d-aa90-0dabc75f3567")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIInspectable)]
    public interface ITokenBrokerInternalStatics
    {
        Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<Windows.Security.Credentials.WebAccount>> FindAllAccountsAsync();
    }

    [Version(1)]
    [MarshalingBehavior(MarshalingType.Agile)]
    [Threading(ThreadingModel.Both)]
    [Static(typeof(Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web.ITokenBrokerInternalStatics), 1)]
    public class TokenBrokerInternal { }

    public static class TokenBrokerInternalAssist
    {
        public static ITokenBrokerInternalStatics GetTokenBrokerInternal()
        {
            var tokenBrokerStatics = WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(typeof(TokenBrokerInternal));
            var statics = (ITokenBrokerInternalStatics)tokenBrokerStatics.ActivateInstance()
return statics;
        }
    }

}
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work despite my best efforts. Here's a couple of errors I've encountered while trying to get this working:

- Casting Errors
- Activation Factories Not Existing
- Many Other Errors related to dumb mistakes

I'm pretty new at this WinRT stuff, but despite looking on multiple sites for answers to my problem, I've found myself at a dead-end, and I really just wanna convert this code to C# to avoid having to compile a C++ project twice to support Any CPU and the complicated compiling of my app. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. This is not a UWP app, so don't suggest `WebAccountManager` or anything UWP specific, please.

Comment: .NET Core3/5/6  or .NET Framework?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.core.webauthenticationcoremanager.findallaccountsasync?view=winrt-22000

Comment: @SimonMourier .Net Framework

Comment: @HansPassant Won't work on NET Framework

Comment: This is WinRT not COM (although WinRT is based on COM, WinRT is quite new). WebAccountProvider works on .NET Framework, just add the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` nuget package. Otherwise, compile your .idl as a `.winmd` file and reference that like a .dll.

Comment: @SimonMourier If I reference the .wimd
`Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Internal.Security.Authentication.Web.ITokenBrokerInternalStatics`
and I'm not trying to make a provider, I'm trying to get the current accounts registered under a windows user